# ReactJs this.state не рендерится, хотя объект в this.state существует

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

this.state не рендерится, хотя объект в this.state существует.

distances является объектом, который получен от google distances API в результате запроса.

Ho если я ставлю вручную в this.state.distances объект, то всё работает как надо.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import SearchComponent from './search_component';

import _ from 'lodash';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            distances: ''
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if(newProps.Distances) {
            this.setState({
                              distances: newProps.Distances
                          })
        }
    }

    renderDistancesList() {
        if(_.isObject(this.state.distances)){
            let d = this.state.distances;
            console.log('this.state.distances ', d);
                return (
                <div>
                    <h4>Distsances:</h4>
                    {
                        _.map(d, (key, value) => {
                            return <li key={key}>{key}</li>
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                )
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <div>HelloFrom App</div>
            <SearchComponent/>
            {this.renderDistancesList()}
        </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ Distances, Origin }) {
    return { Distances, Origin }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что до того как данные пришли `renderDistancesList()` ничего не возвращает, т.к. `return` обернуто в `if` без `else` и это возможно вызывает ошибку.

Попробуйте так:

```
renderDistancesList() {
    if(this.state.distances !== ''){ // это только для теста
        let d = this.state.distances;
        console.log('this.state.distances ', d);
            return (
            <div>
                <h4>Distsances:</h4>
                {
                    _.map(d, (key, value) => {
                        return <li key={key}>{key}</li>
                    })
                }
            </div>
            )
    } else {
      return (<div>Loading data...</div>)
    }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не получилось, но и ошибок нет.Странно.

Comment: никак не могу допереть.что я делаю не так?